# Count how much similar id's exists

Tags: jquery, html

Well, I have an html document containing particular id elements on a table, this ids are composed like this: "word + a number starting by 1 + word", and has a class, that could be "enabled" or "disabled".

It's something like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="enabled" id="Bart1sim"></td>
        <td class="enabled" id="john1doe"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="enabled" id="Bart2sim"></td>
        <td class="enabled" id="john2doe"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="disabled" id="Bart3sim"></td>
        <td class="enabled" id="john3doe"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="disabled" id="Bart4sim"></td>
        <td class="disabled" id="john4doe"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And when click on whatever "enabled" td, the last "enabled" td (let's think that all similar ids are grouping the tds) class must changes to "disabled".
When click on whatever "disabled" td, the last "disabled" td class must changes to "enabled".

I think if I could check by the id's what's the last "enabled" td class of each group, this should works.

This is what I already have but doesn't works:

```
$(document).ready(Principal);

function Principal() {
    $(document).on("click touchend", ".enabled, .disabled", function() {
         LetsDoThis(this.className)
    });
}

function LetsDoThis(clas) {
    if (clas == "enabled")
        $("." + clas + "").removeClass("enabled").addClass("disabled");
    else
        $("." + clas + "").removeClass("disabled").addClass("enabled");
}
```

Thanks for your time.

**Edit**

var num = $('[id^="Bart"]').length gives number of all ids starts with "Bart", but I could have ids like Bart1Fla, Bart2Fla, Bart3Fla.. Bart1Ned, Bart2Ned, Bart3Ned.. which are different id groups, so I still need to check the last word after the number to count the ids.

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use combination of [Attribute Starts With[name^=”value”]](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) and [Attribute Ends With [name$=”value”]](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/) Selector.

You can also use [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) method to add additional checks

```
//Get elements which starts with "Bart" and ends with "sim"
var elements = $('[id^="Bart"][id$="sim"]');

//Additional check
elements.filter(function() {
    return /^Bart[0-9]+sim$/.test(this.id);
});

var num = elements.length;
```

```js
jQuery(function() {
  //Get elements which starts with "Bart" and ends with "sim"
  var elements = $('[id^="Bart"][id$="sim"]');
  
  //Additional check
  elements.filter(function() {
    return /^Bart[0-9]+sim$/.test(this.id);
  });
  
  var num = elements.length
  console.log(num);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="enabled" id="Bart1sim"></td>
    <td class="enabled" id="john1doe"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="enabled" id="Bart2sim"></td>
    <td class="enabled" id="john2doe"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="disabled" id="Bart3sim"></td>
    <td class="enabled" id="john3doe"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="disabled" id="Bart4sim"></td>
    <td class="disabled" id="john4doe"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use [attribute starts with selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) like following.

```js
var num = $('[id^="Bart"]').length

console.log(num);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="enabled" id="Bart1sim"></td>
        <td class="enabled" id="john1doe"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="enabled" id="Bart2sim"></td>
        <td class="enabled" id="john2doe"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="disabled" id="Bart3sim"></td>
        <td class="enabled" id="john3doe"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="disabled" id="Bart4sim"></td>
        <td class="disabled" id="john4doe"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What not you use number at last? It will be easier then. @Pancreatico

Comment: that's true, i'll check if that's possible

Comment: i'll take it, ty so much anyway.

Comment: I'm having this issue when I try to use $('[id=^"'+sinnt+'"]').length  where sinnt is a string variable: Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [id=^"0sa19002200"]

what's wrong?

Comment: solved, was $('[id^="'+sinnt+'"]') and not $('[id=^"'+sinnt+'"]')